# How do I completely remove cilium from Ubuntu 18?

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-18.04, cilium

I installed cilium with:

`kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cilium/cilium/1.7.2/install/kubernetes/quick-install.yaml`

A couple minutes later the network connectivity on the host went down (could connect out from the host but not in from another host).  I deleted cilium with

`kubectl delete -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cilium/cilium/1.7.2/install/kubernetes/quick-install.yaml`

and rebooted.  That restored my network connectivity, but the syslog gets messages like this every 5 seconds:

`Apr 19 10:07:48 tv kubelet[19221]: W0419 10:07:48.258636   19221 cni.go:202] Error validating CNI config list {"cniVersion":"0.3.1","name":"cilium","plugins":[{"cniVersion":"0.3.1","enable-debug":false,"name":"cilium","type":"cilium-cni"}]}: [failed to find plugin "cilium-cni" in path [/opt/cni/bin]]`

What do I have to do to completely remove cilium?

Answer (score 1):

hi，you can try check this directory of each node

```sh
/etc/cni/net.d/05-cilium.conf
```

and delete this file:

```sh
05-cilium.conf
```

e.g:

```sh
rm /etc/cni/net.d/05-cilium.conf
```

Finally, restart the flannel daemonsets

```sh
kubectl rollout restart daemonsets kube-flannel-ds-amd64 -nkube-system
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/aliasmee/6c7e5fb433c8fd303b07f0081fc83677